# Can i decrease leaderboard score?

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I'd like to decrease the score when player loses.
Since leaderboard automatically ignores lower score than it has,
I wonder there are anys way to do this. thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do this as it is not what a leaderboard is intended to do. If you want this kind of functionality you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: You mean i need my own server. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will need your own backend in order to do that.